# Designing a thermoelectric circuit

Tags: circuit-design

I am trying to design a circuit for 5 Thermal Electric Control(TEC)
I am given 2 power sources 1) 0-60V; 0-12A  2) 0-12.5V; 0-60A
The thermostat requires a voltage of 12V to operate and is able to deliver an output of 12V and 10A.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDpU5W.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Each TEC requires a voltage of 12V and a current of 4A to operate. If I connect the modules in parallel I will meet the voltage requirements but not the current requirements. and if I do it in series it will be the opposite. I thought about using transistors, to amplify the current for the parallel connections, but I don't think it will work in a real-life situation. Can anyone help me with this problem? any help will be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: how would you amplify current it the power supply is not capable of supplying it? ... you actually said nothing about the capacity of the power supply, except that it is unable to supply parallel connected modules

Comment: @jsotola using a transistor I can adjust the Base current, let's say 0.2A, The transistor has a gain of 100, resulting in a collector current of 20A. Then I can connect the modules in parallel, each branch having 4A of current. How would you do it?

Comment: Why do you think you need a transistor?  What is the "current requirement" you need to hit?  Give some clues what you are doing.

Comment: @Dugong98 While a transistor can control a higher load current with a smaller control current, it does not magically allow powering four 4A loads unless the current for four 4A loads can be delivered by the power supply. Please edit datasheets of the TEC modules and power supplies.

Comment: @Justme Hi, I have just updated the schematics, the TEC modules must be connected to the thermostat that is able to supply 12V and 10A. If I connect it in parallel, I will need 20A divided across 5 branches, this is where I am facing the problem! Thank you!

Comment: `resulting in a collector current of 20A` ... where would the current come from? ... your post implies that the power supply is not capable of driving all of the modules

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all TEC designs are actually quite complicated, so the performance is probably not going to be what you expect.

But.. to address your question directly, if you use 6 TECs instead you could use 3 parallel sets of 2 in series. That should stay below your power supplies current limit. Each TEC would effectively see 6V and would draw less current.

You could even put them all in series. That would work and be the most efficient configuration, but it would also give you the least cooling.

TECs are more efficient when run at low voltage FYI. The cooling is proportional to the current, but the heating goes up by current^2.

Comment: Hello thank you for your answer! What i'm facing isn't staying below the current limit,  but not having enough currrent to supply the 5 TEC. The required current is 20A (5 x 4A) but i only am able to supply 10, for the parallel connection

Comment: If you built the circuit in your diagram the TECs would try to pull 20A and the PSU breaker would trip. If you hooked 3 sets of 2 in series they would draw approx 2A per set for a total of 6A.

Comment: There is no magic solution where all the TECs run at full power. Your supply can put out 120W (10A*12V), the TECs at full power draw 240W (4A * 5 * 12V). Therefore there is not enough power available, and no arrangement of the circuit can change that.